# Old answer unaccepted and not so very good answer accepted

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, sock-puppets

Some time today one of my old [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704139/winsock-programming-connecting-to-a-public-ip/45704801#45704801) got unaccepted and a new one posted just today got accepted. What is surprising is that the accepted answer is just a single line which does not even answer the question.

Another fishy part is that the account which posted the new answer is deleted. (By the user or otherwise, I am not aware).

One explanation could be that the user created a new account and wanted to boost it so just switched some accepted answers. I checked the OPs other question. But the "accept" votes haven't been switched.

Any idea of what might have prompted the OP to change the accepted answer in this particular instance?

Comment: No.  The OP's in sole control of answer acceptance.  For all we know, a hamster devil appeared on their mouse and unaccepted your answer.  Not much else we can do about it, really.

Comment: @Makoto if a mod can look at the time the new account was created and the time the vote was switched, we might know if the OP is trying something fishy.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: yes, there was something fishy, and we already handled it. Sorry, we can't  give you the accept mark back.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not really about the accept mark. Was trying to figure out the reason. As explained by BoltClock, it appears to be common.

Comment: I mean, I'm probably exaggerating there. But I do see it from time to time.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: well, not *that* common. I've written 18k answers and it hasn't happened to me yet. But from the point of moderators, among people that try to cheat the system this happens more than we'd like to see. Although, we'd like to see all fraud disappear, so *any* such behaviour is more than we'd like to see ;-)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: You're lucky, then. I'm pretty sure it's happened to me at least once, but I don't even remember the year it happened.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Apart from the fraud it is just that a "bad" answer stays accepted and we all for quality of our content.

Comment: Congrats, you got your accept back.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That was a sock puppet. What this user did is a fairly common way to completely and utterly disrespect the time and effort others have put into their answers.

Unfortunately we can't reverse or change anyone's accept votes. The most we can do is delete the sock puppet and its answer, and warn/suspend the user for gaming the system. Sorry this happened to you.

Comment: I see, my intention for posting this question was to just know what might have happened. Thank you for clarifying. Not worried about the accept mark beyond the fact that the accepted answer is NAA.

Answer (score 11):

If you honestly believe that there is voting fraud going on, the flag one of the relevant posts and explain your suspicions for a moderator to evaluate.

If you don't have reason to believe that there's voting fraud going on, and just don't like the new accepted answer as much, then there isn't really anything for you to do.  You could comment, if you wanted, on how the post could be improved, and perhaps downvote it if you think it's not useful, but that's really about it.